# How to Eliminate the error saying "The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted"?

Tags: ios, unicode, localization

In my application I Enable Localization after freezing my UI. I enable spanish first and got everything working fine.

But I got this error after enabling Chinese language, The error occurred in the file        InfoPlist(Chinese)

Below are the contents of that file

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */

"CFBundleDisplayName"="喜欢它"
```

Below is the error message

```
/User/Imp ones/ProjName/ProjName/zh-Hans.lproj
/InfoPlist.strings:0: error: read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it has been corrupted.
```

I don't know how to solve this, Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh it's my fault I forget to add semicolon at the end of the key value pair so I change the contents of InfoPlist file like below

```
/* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */

"CFBundleDisplayName"="喜欢它";
```